# Lint only the pushed commit file on azure pipeline

Tags: javascript, yaml, azure-pipelines, eslint, super-linter

I am trying to lint only the pushed files but the following yaml file only validates the whole codebase not the pushed file.

```html
trigger:
- development-test

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: PreDeployment
  jobs:
    - job: Code_Validation
      steps:
      - script: |
          docker pull github/super-linter:latest    
        displayName: Pull github/super-linter docker image
 
      - script: |
          docker run \
            -e VALIDATE_CODE_BASE=false
            -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/tmp/lint github/super-linter
        displayName: super-linter validation
```

Answer (score 1):

Your env **VALIDATE_CODE_BASE** should be **VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE**

from https://github.com/github/super-linter#environment-variables :

| ENV VAR | Default Value | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE | `true` | Will parse the entire repository and find all files to validate across all types. **NOTE:** When set to `false`, only **new** or **edited** files will be parsed for validation. |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Thank You for pointing out the mistake but VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE=false still return the following error::
2022-03-02 05:35:32 [FATAL]   []
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.